# DynamoDB one-to-many design thoughts and issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am building a web application using AWS DynamoDB as the database for my application. To be honest I am quite a newbie to the AWS DyanmoDB. One of the reasons I use DynamoDB is because I want to learn it. Now, I am having a bit of a problem designing my tables around the one-to-many relationship.

Now, I have a table with the following attributes.

```
RegionName (PK) | PostId (RK) | ExpiresAt (LSI) | Message | CreateAt | Topic (LSI) | Status (LSI) |
```

I put all the data in one table. I have read in my articles about DynamoDB saying that it is always the first step to understand the Access Pattern before designing the tables. The followings are the access pattern to my database.

- All the regions
- All the posts from a region
- All the posts from a region that will expire before
- All the posts in a region with the status open and topic, "Astronomy"

There are still some more of course. But I found the followings issue with storing all the data or attributes in one single table.

- I cannot update the RegionName because it is the partition key.
- I can't update the Topic or Status or ExpiresAt attributes because they are local secondary index.
- I cannot add the new regions without adding the post with it because I am using the composite primary key. For example, I might add the new region as admin of the website. Then some parts of my website will be displaying a list of regions.

So, how can I solve these problems? Is my design correct?

To solve the region problem, as a newbie to the DynamoDB, I tried to split the tables into two. Region table and Post table. Then Post table will have the region_id. This way, I can add the new region separately. But is it the correct way to solve the problems?

Comment: It sounds like you also have an access pattern to fetch all regions.  You may want to update your list of required access patterns to reflect this, as it will certainly change your data model.

Comment: Yes, I updated the question to include a new access pattern to fetch all the regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're off to a great start.  Here's my take on implementing your first three access patterns.  Keep in mind that there are *many* ways to model data in DynamoDB and this is just one of them.

I'm implementing your access patterns using two global secondary indexes.  The base table looks like this:

[image]

The base table will implement your "get posts by region" access pattern.

For your second access pattern, "fetch posts by expiration date", I created GSI2 using the PK of the base table and an SK of the expiration time.  This will let you filter for posts in a region based on the expires_at time:

[image]

Your third access pattern, "fetch post within a region by status and topic", I've opted to take a slightly different approach.  I created a new field named `status_topic` which concatenates the status and topic fields.  I then defined another GSI using the PK of the main table and an SK of `status_topic`.  That view looks like this:

[image]

This lets you implement your third access pattern by searching GSI1 where `PK = REGION#<region_id> and SK = OPEN#ASTRONOMY`.  Notice this pattern also lets you search for posts by status: `PK = REGION#<region_id> and SK begins_with OPEN#` or `PK = REGION#<region_id> and SK begins_with CLOSED#`

You also mention that you have an access pattern around listing all regions.  A simple way to do this would be to create a separate partition that lists all available regions:

[image]

If you have access patterns around regions (e.g. fetch region by name) or many regions, you might consider creating an item *collection* to store the regions:

[image]

Notice I replaced the region names with numerical ID's and moved the name into an attribute.  This is to illustrate that you can make the region name separate from the unique primary key.

Hope this helps get you unstuck!

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Yes, this did give me a great start. But how will I add a new region without adding the post?

Comment: Also, what if I want to update the region name? For example, REGION#EAST to something else? Because it is the partition key, DyanmoDB will not allow me to update it.

Comment: Also, let's say I created a GSI using ExpiresAt as the Range Key. What if I want to update the ExpiresAt? It would not allow me because it is part of the key?

Comment: In this example, I am modeling regions in their own REGIONS partition.  To add a new region, simply add a new item with PK=REGION and SK=REGION#<region-id>.

Comment: DynamoDB will not prevent you from updating an attribute that is used in the primary key of a GSI.  As a matter of fact, that is part of what makes GSIs so useful.  If your posts have their expires_at time updated, their sort order in the GSI will automatically be updated.

Comment: I would recommend storing your region names as an attribute on the region item, you can update those as much as you'd like.  Avoid encoding your data within the primary key only.

Comment: Hello Seth, really appreciate that you got back. Can you pls also tell me how I can solve the problem of updating ExpiresAt? If I create a new GSI using ExpiresAt range key and I update the ExpiresAt on the main table, will the ExpiresAt attribute on the GSI be updated too? Can you please explain to me a little bit more about it?

Comment: Also, you created a separate row with REGIONS as partition keys just to store the array of all regions. So that in this way I can create a new region without adding a new post. But if I am to update the name of the existing region, I will need to make sure that I also update the related item in the array. Am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232917/discussion-between-seth-geoghegan-and-wai-yan-hein).

Comment: Hello, this should be the last question. Is this the Single Table Design?

Comment: Yes, this solution is in a single table.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again.

Comment: What about there is another column called type which is let's say integer. I want it to be a dedicated column? Then I want to facilitate this access pattern, "All the posts in a region that the topic is Match and ExpiresAt is xxxxx-xx-xx and Type is 2"? Global Secondary Index allows us to have only 2 keys as well. Can you please enlighten me more?